# How do I stop timer on view transition?

Tags: ios, timer, nstimer

I have this timer

```
NSTimer *timer;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0f
                                     target:self selector:@selector(updateCounter:)
                                   userInfo:_TimeLabel.text repeats:YES];
```

in what event should I add the code

```
 [timer invalidate];
```

if I want to stop this timer if I change views? e.g from tableviewcontroller to detailviewcontroller?

Comment: Are you using storyboard.

Comment: It's also good practice to nil out the instance variable (for example if your method that invalidates the timer is called more than once and the instance variable hasn't been set to nil and the NSTimer instance has been deallocated, it will throw an exception).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view controller has a number of methods that you can override to interact with its view being shown and hidden, use now of those:

1. `viewWillDisappear:`
2. `viewDidDisappear:`

*(Be sure to call `super` as part of your implementation)*